# TFS 2008 Backup options

Tags: team-foundation-server

I am running a TFS2008 developpment environment without any backup options so far, and it is ideal time for to get one setup. can someone suggest better approach in terms of daily backup of TFS2008 server.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach than not backing it up? Sure, back it up. You should find what you need here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552295(VS.90).aspx